# Outlook form region not activated when opening .msg file

Tags: outlook-addin, msg, outlook-form

I am working on an Outlook add-in with two form regions registered for IPM.Note. I use Visual Studio 2012, C# and Outlook 2010/2013/2016.

It generally works as expected, but with Outlook closed, then if I open a .msg file, Outlook seems to open in a special mode (the same as if I use command-line option /f). One particular thing about this mode is that my form regions do not show. In particular, the methods of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.FormRegionStartup are not called at all.

Is this by design or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you check out the COM add-ins list? Is your add-in listed as active there?

Comment: Other parts of the add-in works in this special mode, thus it is not disabled.